# How to align elements equally in a line in CSS/Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The current codes can be found here:

http://www.bootply.com/11CfWtCAbX#

And What I want looks like this:

[image]

The main problem is I don't know how to align the circles equally to fill the row.. Though Bootstrap has a Grid System, it only accept integer such as `col-lg-2` but not `col-lg-1.5`. In my case, there are 8 circles, so I have no idea how to align them easily.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: I've also found your .circle class is Over-riding the col-lg CSS I would stick circle class inside the columns as a separate div

Comment: You cant use dot in class name. Css detects it such a new class after dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own cols. See: http://www.bootply.com/AnCCbwcwEA

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="myCol">
      <div class="circle"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- Seven more circles here -->
</div>
```

CSS: `.myCol` has a `width` of `12.5%`, because 100/8 = 12.5%.
`.circle` has `margin: 0 auto` for centering the circle within `.myCol`

```
.circle {
  background: #A9A9A9;
    height:30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
.myCol
{
  width: 12.5%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your issue. You can use an offset of col-lg-offset-2 in the beginning. Tus if there are 8 circles and the div is divided into 12 parts. The first two parts will be empty and the next 8 will have circles and the last two will empty.

This is the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inline-block` elements and justified text as suggested [here](http://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/) to achieve that

HTML

```
<div class＝"container">
<h1>Test</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" id="box">
      <div class="text-center">Data Quality</div>
      <div class="row inline-row">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
    background: #A9A9A9;
    height:30px;
    width: 30px;
    border-radius:50%
}

.inline-row {
     text-align: justify;
}

.inline-row div {
    display: inline-block; 
}

.inline-row:after {
      width: 100%;
      content: " ";
      display: inline-block;
 }
```

bootply: http://www.bootply.com/MtJN37CkS5